# Drawing a symbolic function either in R or Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, symbolic-math

I want to draw this equation either in Matlab or R (Matlab is preferred) :

```
f = p+(1-p)*(T-S)
```

where `0 < S < 1`, `0 < p < 1` and `T` is a constant. I want to draw the function and find the min, max based on `S` and `p`. My basic problem is defining the span of the graph as a symbol. Since S changes from 0 to T.

Comment: Looks like homework. You should show some effort before expecting us to do your work.

Comment: Read through the help on the symbolic math toolbox. For example, [Calculus demo](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/symbolic/symcalcdemo.html)

Comment: My problem is basically defining the limit using symobls. Since S changes from 0 to T.

Comment: You should look at `?wireframe` for examples on how to set this up for lattice functions.

Comment: @DWin I installed the wireframe, I will give an update on it. It seems you are an expert on stats. I have a question for you if you don't mind to take a look at it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ezsurf` to plot. For example:

```
f = 'p + (1 - p) * (5 - S)'
ezsurf(f, [0 5 0 1])
```

[image]

Then use regular calculus to find critical values, double differentiate to find their type, and so on...

This is all explained in the online documentation (`diff`, `solve`, etc.). Also, this external example covers all of the points you want very nicely: http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math50c/matlab/maxmin/index.xhtml

Comment: Thank you so much dear. So there is now way to define the ranges as symbols and draw them based on different symbols ?.